# awk prints unnecessary new line in output

Tags: linux, shell, elasticsearch, awk, console

I am trying to create csv file from the below data(Elasticsearch data)

```
health status index                                                uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   78_data_store-2021.12.12                              cYZDB7NGQbyowP-WyF99Zw   1   1    5438232            0      8.3gb          4.1gb
green  open   78_data_store-2021.12.24                             RWrhN4QKT2OlbP4MB7CYmw   1   1     663431            0    745.3mb        372.6mb
green  open   78_data_store-2021.11.26                              CivwBCtAROCejmpZ6RaXOA   1   1     989983            0    956.5mb        478.2mb
```

I want below output (**Expected output**)

```
78,78_data_store-2021.11.26,2021.11.26,1,1,478.2mb
78,78_data_store-2021.12.12,2021.12.12,1,1,4.1gb 
78,78_data_store-2021.12.24,2021.12.24,1,1,372.6mb
```

But when I am using below command I got unnecessary new line in output

```
cat filename | grep " 78_" | sort -k 3 | awk '{split($3,a,"_");print a[1];split($3,a,"-"); print ","  $3 "," a[2] "," $5 "," $6 "," $10}'
```

**output of this command**

```
78
,78_data_store-2021.11.26,2021.11.26,1,1,478.2mb
78
,78_data_store-2021.12.12,2021.12.12,1,1,4.1gb
78
,78_data_store-2021.12.24,2021.12.24,1,1,372.6mb
```

What is the missing in the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` adds a newline by default. You can use `printf("%s", a[1]);` instead or move the printing of `a[1]` to where all the other fields are being printed. I've renamed the first use of `a` into `b` instead be be able to keep the value until later:

```
grep " 78_" filename | sort -k 3 | \
awk '{split($3,b,"_");split($3,a,"-"); print b[1] ","  $3 "," a[2] "," $5 "," $6 "," $10}'
```

Output:

```
78,78_data_store-2021.11.26,2021.11.26,1,1,478.2mb
78,78_data_store-2021.12.12,2021.12.12,1,1,4.1gb
78,78_data_store-2021.12.24,2021.12.24,1,1,372.6mb
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Using `Schwartzian transform` in `awk`. Also using `awk` + `sort` + `awk` combination here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
FNR>1 && /78_/{
  split($3,arr,"[_-]")
  print arr[4]"@"arr[1],$3,arr[4],$5,$6,$NF
}
' Input_file | 
sort -t'@' -k1 | 
awk '{sub(/^[^@]*@/,"")} 1'
```

***Explanation for above code:***

- Passing Input_file(OP's file) into `awk` program.
- Setting `OFS` as comma here for all lines.
- Checking condition if its greater than 1st line and having 78_ in it then only move further.
- Using `split` function to split 3rd field into an array named arr where delimiters are `_-` here.
- printing `arr[4]"@"arr[1],$3,arr[4],$5,$6,$NF` which is as per needed output, only thing is additionally `arr[4]@` is added front of the output so that we can sort it easily(could be removed later in this program).
- Passing `awk` program's output to `sort` command where setting field separator as `@` and sorting it with 1st field(eg: 2021.12.12 in shown samples).
- Passing sorted data to another `awk` program where removing everything from starting of value till 1st occurrence of `@`(which was added additionally as mentioned in previous step).

***Improvements in OP's attempts:***

- We need not to use `grep` when we are using `awk`, it can take care of searching string itself, so removed it from answer.
- We need not to use 2 times `split` that could also be merged into a single `split` by mentioning multiple separators in `split`.